# Hilbert's Theorem in Higher Dimensions

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

[Hilbert's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_theorem_(differential_geometry)) tells us that we cannot **immerse** a surface of constant negative curvature into $\mathbb{R}^3$.

My questions:

1, What is the difference between an "immersion" and an "embedding"?

2, When we talk about $\mathbb{R}^3$ above, we are not specifying a metric so surely we can think of Minkowski space as $M^{2,1}=(\mathbb{R}^3,g_M)$ where $g_M$ is the Minkowski metric. Why can we not construct an immersion of $\mathbb{H}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ using this approach - what fails?

3, Why is the hyperboloid $\mathbb{H}^2$ referred to as a "model" of hyperbolic space?

4, Hilbert's Theorem is only stated for $\mathbb{R}^3$. What happens when we go to more than 3 dimensions?

Comment: 1. An embedding of manifolds is also homeomorphism onto its image. An immersion is just a map with injective derivative. Any embedding is also an immersion. 2. Actually, we do (although implicitly) assume the euclidean metric (Hilbert's theorem is about isometric immersions). 3. What is your definition of the hyperboloid?

Comment: 2, I see. So should I read Hilbert's Theorem about isometric embeddings as saying that we can't embed it into R^3 using Euclidean metric but that if we give up that assumption, it is possible with Minkowski metric? And my understanding of the hyperboloid is the surface -x0^2+x1^2+...+xn^2=-1